# First step on Google API + GMAIL = bad request

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm very new on Google API, Eventually I want to send emails using it. But for now I'm trying something a little bit simpler (and then build it up).

List all emails in the inbox.

From [`Gmail > API > Reference`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference), I followed these steps:

On Google API Console:

1. Created my application.
2. Under `API & Services > Credentials` I created a user with `Project/Owner` role (just to make sure there is no permission problems in this step).
3. Then I created a key and download the json file.
4. At `API & Services > Library` I enabled Gmail.

And using the Reference I put together this snippet:

app.ts

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import credentials from './credentials';

async function main() {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    credentials,
    scopes: [
      'https://mail.google.com/',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata'
    ]
  });

  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: authClient });

  const data = await gmail.users.messages.list({ userId: 'me' });

  console.log(data);
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

package.json

```
...

"dependencies": {
  googleapis": "^48.0.0"
}

...
```

Every time I ran this snippet I got:

> [01] GaxiosError: Bad Request
>   [02]     at Gaxios._request (~\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:85:23)
>          ...
>   [06]   response: {
>          ...
>   [35]     status: 400,
>   [36]     statusText: 'Bad Request',
>   [37]     request: {
>   [38]       responseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages'
>              ...

I tried many diferent configurations on Google API Console. Tried to change the scope (list of urls from line 8 to 12) for many others, change the credentials.json to a .js and .ts format, put in a global variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) instead of a direct import. But despite of all my attempts, I got aways the same error.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out example from [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/gmail/list.js) which does exactly what you want. They seem use a [sampleclient](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/sampleclient.js) instead of a `credentials` library.

Comment: `sampleclient` use `google.auth.OAuth2` witch require a client_id and client_secret to be instanced, in other words this auth is use to connect with a trird party authentication (user), I'm tring to use a "service to service" authentication like on: 

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/jwt.js

Comment: I see...but what happens when you try to use `google.auth.OAuth2` instead of `google.auth.GoogleAuth` in a server-to-server setup? I am imagining auth woes?

Comment: When I create a "server to server" I don't have a client_id and a client_secret, instead I have a credential.json file.

Comment: you'll still have a client id, no? Sometime back I used this example https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button and it still requires a client id. I'm not sure what happens if you add gmail in the scope, will it let you fetch the mails (seems risky though)